# Inequalities: relating difference of probabilities to a event of the difference of two rvs

Tags: probability, inequality

I've struggling with the following homework question for a while. Any hints would be appreciated:

Let $X, Y$ be non-negative integer-valued random variables. Show that:
$$
|P(X=0) - P(Y=0)| \leq E|X-Y|
$$

From the right side I reckon that the idea will be to apply Markov's inequality. I guess that somehow I'll use that $P(X\geq1) \leq EX$, or combination of $X,Y$ that I can apply Markov's to.

My problem is relating the difference of two the two probabilities to any event involving the two of them at the same time where I can apply Markov's. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $E|X-Y|$ or $E(X-Y)$?

Comment: The absolute value, as it is. And also, it should be different from $|EX -EY|$..